# Can I change a hood range blower to work with an inline duct work?

Tags: range, blower, hood

I purchased a Zline range hood that has a remote blower that goes in an attic by mistake. I need the duct work to go outside before the ceiling height. Can I put a blower in the middle of the duct work that will work with the hood controls?

Comment: Why not return it and get one that has the blower where you need it? Not installing it in accordance with the directions _could_ void the warranty...

Comment: you should be asking the manufacturer, not some strangers on the internet

Comment: If you put the blower in the middle, like you want, can it be accessed for cleaning? (Frankly, even the attic sounds terrible to me, but at least you can get at it.)